# Calling end() after appendTo()

Tags: jquery

I'm curious, why does calling `appendTo()` method on a jQuery object is considered a filtering operation ? For example, `end()` returns the set of matched elements from the previous filtering operation:

```
obj.slice(0, 3).appendTo('#row1').end().end()
```

But, I need to calld `end(`) twice to get original elements after appending, because somehow `appendTo()` is considered filter operation.So why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appendTo` traverses the DOM and filters based on your selector, allowing it to match multiple elements. This makes it a filtering operation.

Comment: And the line to back that up: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/manipulation.js#L530

Comment: And a demo of changing that line to just return `this` http://jsfiddle.net/XH5eV/ causing it to have the expected (in OP) results